# Why does lord Shiva wear a Naga (snake) around his neck?

Tags: shiva, symbolism

As you can see in many pictures of Shiva, he wears a naga wrapped around his neck.

[image: Lord Shiva]
<sup>[Credits for Image](http://www.mobileapples.com/Wallpapers_Detail.aspx?Title=Lord%20Shiva%20Wallpaper%20&Sno=10715)</sup>

So is there any reason behind keeping that naga around his neck, or is that a vahan for lord Shiv just like lord Ganesha has a rat or like the goddess Mata Ji who has a tiger?

I know that he is known as Pasupathinath, which means "lord of all creatures", and that he controls all the animals. Since snake is feared by most of us, is that the reason he wears them around his neck?

Also, does he wear just one, or there are multiple?

Comment: Nagas were very first Shiva linga worshippers

Comment: I think the ultimate god is the goddess (only Devi not durga,parvathi,sathi etc) In devipurana or devi bagavatha it is written that shiva played sivatandava after the death of sathi with her body rotated in his neck,hands,legs,hip wherever he rotated that places decerated by nagas or snakes.

Comment: Kundalini is in serpent form .One gets ashta siddhis when kundalini raises up. All those maha siddhis are dangerous like the serpents.
Since Shiva keeps keeps sidhis under his control and uses them for the welfare of world,it is represented as his abharana.
[Reference](http://www.amazon.in/Sripada-Vallabha-Charithamrutham-Shankara-Bhattu/dp/B00HQZFU4S)

Comment: MńagģSnake indicates kundalini shakthi if one dies shiva uoasena his kundalini will reach till neck wheres if one  dies vishnu opens hismmi9p0⁷9⁹

Answer (score 6):

Lord Shiva wears snakes as his ornaments as well as for his Yajnopavitam (sacred thread). The snake Vasuki which often encircles neck of Lord Shiva can also work like Agni tatwa (fire element) for the Soma tatwa (moon) which is on the head of Lord Shiva. Thus by combining Agni and Soma, Amrita (immortal nectar) is produced which bathes Shiva. Now let's see all these things in scriptures:

### - Snakes as ornament and sacred thread:

In the **Skandha Purana**, Kedar Khanda chapter 22, there is a description of form of Shiva. The verses which are relevant to the snakes are as:

> यज्ञोपवितविधिना उरसा बिभ्रंत वृतम्॥ 
>  वासुकिं सर्पराजं च कंबलाश्वतरौ तथा॥ २२.३ ॥
>  कर्णद्वये धारयंतं तथा कर्कोटकेन हि॥
>  पुलहेन च बाहुभ्यां धारयंतं च कंकणे॥ २२.४ ॥
>  सन्नृपुरे शङ्खकपद्मकाभ्यां संधारयंतं च विराजमानम्॥
>  कर्पूरगौरं शितिकंठमद्भुतं वृपान्वितं देववरं ददर्शुः॥ २२.५ ॥
>  तदा ब्रह्मा च विष्णुश्च ऋषयो देवदानवाः॥
>  तुष्टुवुर्विविधैः सूक्तैर्वेदोपनिपदन्वितैः॥ २२.६ ॥ (Kedar Khanda chapter 22) 
> **As a sacred thread he was wearing Vasuki**, the king of serpents, as well as the Nagas **Kambala** and **Asvatara** on his chest.
> **Karkotaka** was worn by him in the ears as ear-rings and **Pulaha** as bangles round his arms. He appeared brilliantly shining with
> **Sankhaka** and **Padmaka** as his anklets. Suras saw the blue-throated mysterious lord, the most excellent one among Devas, white in complexion like camphor and accompanied by the bull.Then Brahma, Vishnu, the Sages, Devas and Danavas eulogized him with various hymns from the Vedas and the Upaniṣhads.

So, it is clear from above verses that Lord Shiva is wearing various serpents as his ornaments as well as the snake Vasuki as his sacred thread.

### - Vasuki snake as Agni tatwa to the Soma (moon) on head:

The heat produced from the Vasuki snake which encircles neck of Lord Shiva can also cause the Soma (moon) element to exude Amrita (Immortal nectar) which then bathes Lord Shiva. In the **Padma Purana** Uttara Khanda chapter 10, we witness one such incident. The relevant verses are as:

> एवं वदति संप्राप्तौ सुतौ स्कंदविनायकौ || २६ || 
>  तस्मिन्काले देवदेवो यतवागंगमर्दनम् |
>  चकार च करैर्व्यस्तैर्वासुकिर्भूतलेऽपतत् || २७ ||
>  हेरंबवाहनस्याखोः पुच्छं ग्रस्तमथाहिना |
>  स्वपत्रं ग्रस्तमालोक्य मुंचमुंचेत्युवाच ह || २८ ||
>  अत्रांतरे स्कंदवाहं क्षुब्धं वीक्ष्य महास्वरम् |
>  तद्भयाद्वासुकिर्ग्रस्तमाखुपुच्छमथोद्गिरत् || २९ ||
>  अथारुह्य हरस्यांगं गलमावेष्ट्य संस्थितः |
>  तस्य निश्वासपवनैरथ जातो हुताशनः || ३० ||
>  तस्योष्मणा चंद्र लेखा जटाजूटाटवी स्थिता |
>  सार्द्रतां तु तदा सायात्प्लावितं तद्वपुर्यथा || ३१ ||
>  तस्याह्यमृतधाराभिर्ब्रह्ममस्तकमालिका |
>  हरमौलिकपालानामभूत्संजीविता तदा || ३२ ||
>  पपाठ पूर्वमभ्यस्तं सर्वयोगश्रुतिक्रमम् |
>  श्रुत्वा परस्पराधीतं विवदंति शिरांस्यथ || ३३ || (Padma Purana 6.10)
> When he was speaking like this, the two sons of Shiva, Kartikeya and Gajanana came there. At that time, the god of gods was massaging his body with his hands. Due to his hands being tossed about, **Vasuki fell on the ground**. Then the serpent Vasuki seized the tail of the mouse, the vehicle of Gajanana (Ganesha). Seeing his vehicle seized, he said: "Leave it, leave it." In the meanwhile, seeing the agitated vehicle, of a large note, of Skanda, Vasuki ejected, through his fear, the tail of the mouse, which he had seized; **and then mounting upon Shiva's body, he encircled his neck and remained there. Due to its heat, the crescent moon remained in the forest of his matted hair. She (i.e. the crescent moon) then became wet, and bathed his body with Amrita (ambrosia); the row of the skulls on Shiva's head was brought back to life.** And they recited all the sacred texts in due order, which they had formerly studied. The heads, hearing recital (of the sacred text) done by one another, discussed it.

Thus, in the above story it is clear that heat generated from Vasuki caused the Soma (moon) on the Shiva's head to exude Amrita (immortal nectar) which bathed Lord Shiva. Due to the effect of Amrita even the skulls which Lord Shiva was wearing came back to life and began to recite sacred texts.