# I want to know the reason behind lord Shiva wearing snake around his neck and how he got the third eye

Tags: shiva

I am Shruthi. I am a devotee of lord Shiva. I just want know few things regarding lord Shiv's appearance.Like he is wearing snake around his neck,his thrishul, the bhasma ,the reason for his third eye. Can anybody give me the exact answers for all these.

Regards
Shruthi.

Comment: Reason for Shiva having a snake around his neck is given here-http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/470/why-does-lord-shiva-wear-a-naga-snake-around-his-neck?rq=1.

Comment: Related http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/470/why-does-lord-shiva-wear-a-naga-snake-around-his-neck not duplicate.

Comment: Related http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/808/why-does-lord-shiva-have-three-eyes not duplicate.